# iPhone not responding to media queries/meta tag

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, media-queries, mobile-safari

I have multiple (vanilla) CSS media queries on my NextJS website. The media queries work fine on my desktops browser, but when I open the website on my phone, the media queries do not work. I have checked caniuse.com, and all of the CSS properties I am using should work on Safari for iOS. For reference, I have the latest version of safari installed on my iPhone. I read on many sites that NextJS does not automatically have the following meta tag like react does and that it has to be put in manually:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1"></meta>
```

I put that inside of my `<Head></Head>` tag in `_app.tsx`, but my phones browser is still not responding to the media queries.TYA!

Here is an example of a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) or (max-height: 700px) {
  body {
    background-color: var(--lightBlue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the actual media query?

Comment: I updated the post with one

Comment: try using `and` instead of `or`. ------ `@media only (max-width: 1200px) and (max-height: 700px) {
  body {
    background-color: var(--lightBlue);
  }
}`

Comment: That works, but I need to use ```or``` to get the intended style on certain sizes. Do you know if there is an alternative to the ```or```?

Comment: I can just use two separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

I used `or` on multiple queries, which Safari on iOS does not support/respond to. Switching it with `and` or creating multiple queries works.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment.

No need for two separate queries. You can also use a comma to separate two (or more) different rules in one query.

```css
@media (max-width: 1200px), screen and (max-height: 700px) {
  body {
    background-color: var(--lightBlue);
  }
}
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

> You can use a comma-separated list to apply styles when the user's device matches any one of various media types, features, or states.